# How to export whole file into a namespace in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm porting a library to TypeScript and I experience some difficulties with declaration files.

I have a something.ts file which contains some definitions.
I also have a index.d.ts in the root of my project.

In my original index.js there are clause like:

```
exports.accounts = require('./accounts.js')
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
export * as accounts from './accounts'
```

But apparently I can't, why? What am I missing? It strongly feels like a important missing feature in order to migrate projects incrementally.

Thanks.

---

EDIT

By the way I tried to do:

```
declare namespace accounts {
    export * from './accounts'
}
```

But it does not work either.

I don't want to create a .d.ts file in addition the the .ts file I already have and which contains my functions definition.

Comment: How does `index.d.ts` look like? Also what exactly is not working?

Comment: if you're just exporting the accounts module in an `index.ts` file you should be able to just `export * from './accounts'`

Comment: Leave the  `declare` out for your own/project namespace.